# Datepicker with input tag

Tags: angular, typescript

I would change this lable tag `<label>{{list.createdat | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</label>` on input tag, to create a simple datapicker:

`<input type="date"/>`

But in `<label>` tag i have parse data from server, and i dont know how bind `<input>` tag with this `list.createdat`

How to write a correct syntax? Like this? :

```
<input type="date"/ {list.createdat | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}>
```

At finally, i would something like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a directive ("this directive") in your question. I have no idea at all what the question is about.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer i change my question

Comment: What's the current behavior? What's the expected behavior? Actually I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer i've update one more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="date">` requires a string and doesn't work with a `Date` instance.

```
<input type="date" [value]="list.createdat">
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MnfpwDIGhRXTR9fpPWuA?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But my `list.createdat` is data from server.

Comment: Why do you think this makes a difference?

Comment: `creatdate` is a dynamic data from server, but not `2016-01-01`

Comment: You can use `[value]="list.createdat.toLocaleDateString(...)` where `...` is explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString ("using options")